# Logging to multiple files using Pyhon Logging

Tags: python-3.x, logging, fastapi

I've wrote a class to handle my logs but now i need to sepparate some information to another log file. I thought the logger would just get the file from the instance but it's still using my "default" file. I think it may be related to FastAPI because when i start the application it created my "secondary" log file and it writes something from the asyncio library inside.

> [DEBUG] 2024-03-10 15:14:00,345 [asyncio]:  Using proactor: IocpProactor

How can i change the code so it writes to another file when i call the Logger class and pass the filename argument.

Here's the class.

```
import logging
from logging.config import dictConfig
import config

class Logger():
    def __init__(self, filename: str='nexti-app.log', name: str=__name__, *args, **kwargs):
        self.filename = filename
        self.name  = name
        
        __log_level = config.envConfig.get('LOGGING', 'level')
        __log_pasta = config.envConfig.get('LOGGING', 'diretorio')
        __logs_backup = config.envConfig.get('LOGGING', 'quantidade_dias')
        
        __logging_config = {
            'version': 1,
            'formatters': {
                'default': {
                    'format': '[%(levelname)s] %(asctime)s [%(name)-s]:  %(message)s'
                }
            },
            'handlers': {
                'rotate_logs': {
                    'class': 'logging.handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler',
                    'filename': f'{__log_pasta}/{self.filename}',
                    'when': 'midnight',
                    'interval': 1,
                    'backupCount': int(__logs_backup),
                    'formatter': 'default'
                }
            },
            'root': {
                'level': __log_level,
                'handlers': ['rotate_logs']
            }
        }

        dictConfig(__logging_config)
        
    def log(self, msg: str, level: str = 'info') -> None:
        logger = logging.getLogger(self.name)
        
        match level.lower():
            case 'debug':
                logger.debug(msg)
            case 'info':
                logger.info(msg)
            case 'warning':
                logger.warning(msg)
            case 'error':
                logger.error(msg)
            case 'critical':
                logger.critical(msg)
            case _:
                logger.info(msg)
```

Log to two files at the same time based on the instance